# Compare data from 2 array php

Tags: php

i would like to get a result with + or - on values from 2 array.

From array 1 i have a csv file that contain CODE and QTY and in database i have stored not all of CODE from the CSV file so i would like to compare wich one is and if it is how many qty has and compare between 2 .

so i have the next example that i cannot figure out the result.

```
$csv = array(
            0 => array('code'=>100,'qty'=>1),
            1 => array('code'=>200,'qty'=>1),
            2 => array('code'=>300,'qty'=>2),
            3 => array('code'=>400,'qty'=>5),
            4 => array('code'=>500,'qty'=>1),
            5 => array('code'=>600,'qty'=>1)
        );

        $data = array(
            0 => array('code'=>100,'qty'=>1),
            1 => array('code'=>200,'qty'=>1),
            2 => array('code'=>400,'qty'=>1),
            3 => array('code'=>400,'qty'=>1),
            4 => array('code'=>500,'qty'=>1)
        );

        $result = array();


        foreach ($data as $a=>$b) {
                $data_code = $b['code'];
                $data_qty = $b['qty'];

            foreach ($csv as $k=>$v) {
                $csv_code = $v['code'];
                $csv_qty = $v['qty'];

                if ($data_code == $csv_code) {
                    $result[$data_code] = $data_qty - $csv_qty;
                }

                if ($data_code != $csv_code) {
                    $result[$data_code] = $data_qty - $csv_qty;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

any hint is very appreciated !

Comment: I think easier way is to use the "code" as array key on both arrays. This way it will be easier to use foreach ($data as $key => $info) { if (! empty($csv[$key])) {...} }

Comment: Hey this is just a (good-minded) hint: You should learn how to make a short(!), descriptive an reproducable example out of your problem.. While preparing  such a short example, you'll likely solve the problem iself, if not, it remains a *really* interesting problem for  stackoverflow

Comment: I dont want to be a bad guy, but if you are here is because in the past you has in the same position im now, so, dont know what very well descroption you want, what i want is to compare if code 500 from csv is in database and compare the quantity. well not just the code 500, all codes from csv, if exist compare if not return the quantity. thanks

Comment: Actually the code introduces some redundancy. Isn't this the same: http://pastebin.com/aBjKPcHL

Comment: i cannot figure it out !

Answer (score 0):

WHat about using "code" as array keys

```
    $csv = array(
        100 => array('code'=>100,'qty'=>1),
        200 => array('code'=>200,'qty'=>1),
        300 => array('code'=>300,'qty'=>2),
        400 => array('code'=>400,'qty'=>5),
        500 => array('code'=>500,'qty'=>1),
        600 => array('code'=>600,'qty'=>1)
    );

    $data = array(
        100 => array('code'=>100,'qty'=>1),
        200 => array('code'=>200,'qty'=>1),
        300 => array('code'=>400,'qty'=>1),
        400 => array('code'=>400,'qty'=>1),
        500 => array('code'=>500,'qty'=>1)
    );

    $result = array();

    foreach ($csv as $k=>$v) {
        $csv_code = $v['code'];
        $csv_qty = $v['qty'];

        if (! empty($data[$k])) {
            $result[$data[$k]['code']] = $data[$k]['qty'] - $csv_qty;
        }
    }
```

As simple as possible.